# django-inlinecss returns error You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-inlinecss

I am trying to load a page as PDF. actually it loaded successfully - without any style or even the images. So I installed django-inlinecss and added it in installed_apps in settings.py and loaded it in template and called it as I was told. but it returns an error

```
You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

and points at:

```
1   {% load inlinecss %}
2   {% load static %}
3   {% inlinecss "css/style.css" %}    <---
```

I don't have any idea how to fix it. Hope someone could help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it worked when I set directory for `STATIC_ROOT`. but there is one thing to be noticed that you have to set another directory for that. Which means `STATIC_URL` and others like `STATIC_FILE_ROOT`, `STATICFILES_DIRS` shouldn't be the same as `STATIC_ROOT`

eg:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FILE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/assets")
```

sorry if that's not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

as the error say you have to specify the path of your static and media files in settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

Comment: its actually a working project. I have already set roots and everything works. Except this one